# computing radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3+(-1)^n)z^n$ which $z \in \mathbb C$ but i'm confused, because by formula I get two different value for odd and even $n$!
Am I right in computing? and if yes, which one should I take?

Comment: Hint: computing $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3\,z^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-z)^n\,$ may be clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I did a bad mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor series is centered at zero. Because we know that it converges in some open disk with center $0$, it suffices to find the positive largest real number such that the series converges. Call the series $f(z)$. Then, for positive real $z$, we clearly have

$$\sum_1^\infty 2z^n \le f(z) \le \sum_1^\infty 4z^n.$$

Each of the series on the ends has radius of convergence $1$, so $f(z)$ must also.

Comment: That's correct, Thank you :)